# "All sites" overview should not require scrolling when selecting a site

Tags: feature-request, design, stackexchange.com

Since I am a regular Stack Overflow follower, I came across this and was shocked a bit regarding the design and user experience perspective.

Attaching picture 1 - it states that I can click any site and view a synopsis about it. Clear!!!

[image: stackexchange dashboard]

Attaching Picture 2 - you can see that when I clicked Webmasters, the design wants me to scroll horizontally to view all information and basically it hides information.

[image: stackexchange dashboard with horizontal scroll]

It would be nice if it did something like below:

[image]

Comment: "...wants me to scroll horizontally to view all information" and, worse, to go to the site ("Visit Site" button). This feels wrong.